# Android: Tab switch - How to update display when switching between tabs?

Tags: android, methods, tabs, switch-statement, android-tabhost

The app I am building has a tabhost with three tabs. The goal is to update the display in the new tab when the switch takes place. I have the following tab change listener set up in the main activity that built the tab host.

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
  public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    //Now what?
  }
});
```

The question is, How do I take the `tabId` given and use it to call a method in that tab?

### Edit

To clarify a bit: when you create an `Intent` for a new tab you specify an Activity Class, an object of which, presumably, is created to handle setup and management of that tab.

```
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Setup.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("setup").setIndicator("",
      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_setup))
        .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

What I am looking for with this question is how to get a reference to that object? In the example above, the `Setup` class is instantiated to handle the “Setup Tab”.

To restate my question now: How do I, from the `OnTabChangeListener`, call a method in the `Setup` class?

Comment: DO you want to call another activity on Tabchange

Comment: Have you checked that link which I have send you It is answering the same what you are asked for any other help reply me

Comment: I want to call _ANY_ activity from the tab change event. Specially the activity that was given when the tab. was created. -- Yes, I checked the link and it does give a lot of useful info on tabs, but it does not answer the question I asked. -- I edited the question added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the solution to the problem is closer to home. Rather than attaching code to the TabHost, the solution involves getting into the Life-Cycle of the activity by overriding the onPause and onResume methods.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Update your UI here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            //Now what?
                  Object.refreshDrawableState();
        }
        });
```

Where Object = any display Object.

Comment: It is the "any display object" that is at the heart of my problem. I need to find a way in the tab change event to distinguish between the Activity objects that were created with each tab.

Comment: This the object which you want to display after the Tab change event